# Identifying all numbers above n with grep

Tags: r, regex

I have a character vector that contains X.1 - X.13 (and in reality, also a lot of other stuff, including both other numbered variables and variables featuring X). I want to locate X.3 - X.13 and to that effect have used `grep` with the following expression:

```
x <- paste0("X.", 1:13)
grep("^X\\.[3-9]{1}|^X\\.[0-9]{2}", x)
```

My question: is there a better, shorter expression that could be used here? I get that this is probably fairly trivial, but I just want to understand regex better.

Comment: how about `val <- as.numeric(gsub("^X\\.","",x)); which(3<= v & v<=13)` ... ?

Comment: Getting rid of the always redundant `{1}` would be a good start.

Comment: sorry, my suggestion might not work with the "lot of other stuff" ...

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern contains two alternatives, `^X\\.[3-9]{1}` matches `X.3` to `X.9` and `^X\\.[0-9]{2}` matches `X.00` to `X.99`. That is not what you are looking for.

To locate just `X.3` to `X.13`, use

```
grep("^X\\.(?:[3-9]|1[0-3])\\b", x)
```

Or, to match in any right-hand side context (no word boundary on the right):

```
grep("^X\\.(?:1[0-3]|[3-9])", x)
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV64pf/1).

Or, if there can be a letter or `_` after the number, replace `\\b` with `(?!\\d)` and be sure to pass `perl=TRUE` to the `grep` function as the lookahead constructs are not supported by the default TRE regex engine:

```
grep("^X\\.(?:[3-9]|1[0-3])(?!\\d)", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV64pf/2).

Another point: the `^` caret is used to denote the start of string. If you mean to match the substring anywhere inside the string, remove it or replace with `\\b` to match `X` that is not preceded with `_`, letters or digits (see yet [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EV64pf/3)).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `X\\.` - a `X.` substring
- `(?:` - start of a group:

  - `1[0-3]` - `1` followed with a digit from `0` to `3`
  - `|` - or
  - `[3-9]`  - 3 to 9
- `)` - end of the non-capturing group
- `\\b` - a word boundary